# How does 20 * 2 billion take as long as 2 * 3 in Big O Notation?

Tags: javascript, big-o

Im studying big O and I came across this

```
function timesTwo(num) {
  return 2 * num
}
let result = timesTwo(5) // 10
let result2 = timesTwo(2000) // 4000
```

then it says this

> Now, which of these do you think will take the longest to compute? 2 * 5 or 2 * 2000?...It’s just one operation (one multiplication). 20 * 2 billion takes as long as 2 * 3. No matter the size of the input, the function takes the same amount of time to compute.

How is that true?? how does that work? it seems to me that 20 * 2 billion would take significantly longer the 2 * 3

To make matters more unclear, it goes on to say this.

```
function manyTimes(num) {
  let total = 4 * num
  return total * 3
}
```

> Now, we wouldn’t say this function has a Big O of 2, it’d still just be a Big O of 1 because we’re looking at the big picture **(1 operation isn’t gonna take significantly longer than 2 for a computer so we can just ignore it)**. No matter what we put in, the number of operations won’t increase in the function, it’s constant time.

can you please explain the bolded text above.. ok 1 operation isnt significantly longer than 2. But what about 1 compared to 20,000 operations?

**Source where I read this information.** [Big O Notation In Javascript](https://www.doabledanny.com/big-o-notation-in-javascript)

Comment: To multiply something by two all you need to do is shift the binary digits to the left. 2000 = `11111010000` 4000 = `111110100000`. 5 = `101`; 10 = `1010`. It's not algorithmically more complex as the input gets larger.

Comment: Re: the second part: whatever you’re reading (remember to cite the source, by the way) is really bad at explaining the concept (and arguably just completely wrong). Time *complexity* is about how functions grow with their inputs, and two algorithms having the same time complexity doesn’t mean they’re going to have the same speed in practice. The reason constant factors don’t matter in big O is *not* that a single operation takes a small amount of time on a computer. I recommend looking for a different learning resource (and won’t re-explain it here, because good ones *are* out there).

Answer (score 2):

Big O doesn't refer to exactly how long it takes for something to process, but rather how the length of the process grows with N inputs. Linear functions grow more slowly than exponential functions, meaning that Linear is faster to process in Big O.

Your example here compares two linear expressions, meaning that the growth for both is the same. I would say that it is inaccurate to say that they take the same time however, but rather that they grow at the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

it's about tail behavior with input n stretching upwards to infinity. we are only concerned about how the tail of computational complexity trends at the end stages of that tail, because we would generally want to build algorithms in mind for the worst case scenario. 20x2billion is still O(n) just as 2x3 is still 0(n)